# Cannot open or start avi movie file error not resolved with correct file path

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, file-format

I have been editing a video in Blender on a Windows 10 machine for a while now, and I am finally ready to render, but when I try to render out as an avi raw movie file, I get the error `Cannot open or start avi movie file error not resolved with correct file path`.

I have seen that other people have fixed this problem by checking if their output file path is writable, closing the windows explorer, and deleting previous renders of the same project.

I have done all of these things and nothing seems to help.

If anyone has any idea of how to fix this problem, your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot Open Or Start AVI Movie File?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31418/cannot-open-or-start-avi-movie-file)